# Connecting to "Iex" or "morningstar" and retrieve data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-datareader, elixir-iex

I try to retrieve historical financial Data from iex or morningstar. For this I use the Following Code.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 10)
facebook = web.DataReader("FB", 'morningstar', start, end)

print(facebook.head())
```

Unfortunatly I get the error message:

> NotImplementedError: data_source='morningstar' is not implemented

or

> ValueError: The IEX Cloud API key must be provided either through the
>   api_key variable or through the  environment variable IEX_API_KEY

depending on which of both sources I use.

I tried to

```
pip uninstall pandas-datareader
pip install pandas-datareader
```

several times and also restarted the kernel but nothing changes. Was there any change to this APIs or am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation:

You need to obtain the `IEX_API_KEY` from `IEX` and pass it to `os.environ["IEX_API_KEY"]`. (https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remote_data.html#remote-data-iex)
I don't know if the IEX API still works.

The `morningstar` is not implemented. The following data sources (at the time of writing) are:

```
    Tiingo
    IEX
    Alpha Vantage
    Enigma
    Quandl
    St.Louis FED (FRED)
    Kenneth French’s data library
    World Bank
    OECD
    Eurostat
    Thrift Savings Plan
    Nasdaq Trader symbol definitions
    Stooq
    MOEX
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me out alot. The link you postet contained all the answers i needed!

Answer (score 0):

You must provide an API Key when using IEX. You can do this using

```
os.environ["IEX_API_KEY"] = "pk_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

or by exporting the key before starting the IPython session.

You can visit iexcloud.io, after creating a student account you will get an API key for free.